# Clock resetting when battery is removed

Tags: clock, scripts

Every time I turn off my phone and remove the battery the clock on it gets reset and it causes problem for some apps I was wondering if there is some other way to sort out the problem
like is it possible somehow with a script to rewrite the default time/date
or like to set the time/date before any app loads up

Comment: Have you enabled Automatic date & time?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio that won't work if your phone is on the flight mode and it takes a while for it to update time and some apps just reset there license